# How to sort different date formats in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

How to sort the different date formats in MongoDB? I need to sort the date which is in the format of '22-Mar-2012'.

Comment: Sorting dates is much easier when you store them in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: Pleas elaborate a bit on what you have already tried and where are you stuck. See also [How to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB native date type allows sorting naturally. If you're using is, you should have no issue, otherwise I'd suggest you migrate your current data to use this format. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates for more on the subject.

Comment: Thanks! This should be helpful. let me try!

Comment: The link is broken and for me on Robomongo 0.8.5/MongoDB 2.6.3 this seems like an arbitrary ordering. The type of the field is listed as `Date` and printed like `2015-11-24 06:00:16.458Z`.